# Multiple styles within a single a href link in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have a link that has both normal and bold font-weights. Like this:

[sample **link**]

and when I hover over any part of the link, I'd like the color of the entire link text to change. I tried:

```
a:visited { color: #000000; }
a:hover { color: #808080; }

<a href="image.png">sample <strong>link</strong></a>
```

However, the issue is that when I hover over it, the bold part doesn't change color and stays black instead of becoming gray. I tried using a span with a css class specifying a hover color instead of the strong tag. While that works for the bold text, it doesn't change color whenever the mouse is over the non-bold part of the link.

What is the the right way to solve this?
Thanks.

Edit: The problem was that I had * { color: #000000; } in the css.

Comment: Try to reload the page with `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`R`

Answer (score 0):

It works for me for the entire link text.

**Clean your browser history**

*https://jsfiddle.net/elouanesbg/gefhcd0a/3/*

```
a:visited { color: #000000; }
a:hover { color: #808080; }
<a href="image.png" >sample <strong >link</strong></a>
```

Comment: Thank you for that link. It was easy to debug my issue there. I had this css element: * {  color: #000000; }. Removing it fixed the problem. Could you explain why this is?

Comment: The css selector (* = all elements) is overwriting the other css selector

Comment: move (* { color: #000000; }) to the top off your css file

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this.

```
a:visited { color: #000000!important; }
a:hover { color: #808080!important; }
```